# Trying to Capture console.log Message from YouTube <iframe>

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

The YouTube HTML5 video `<iframe>` fires a console.log message for various events such as the loading of an ad banner. I'm trying to programmatically capture the console.log message using JavaScript to trigger a function as follows:

```
console['log'] = function(msg){
    // Operate on msg
}
```

To send a console.log message to the YouTube `<iframe>`, the following method works (in longhand for illustrative reference):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[youTubeIframe].contentWindow.console.log(msg);
```

However, the following code *does not work*:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[youTubeIframe].contentWindow.console['log'] = function(msg){
    // Operate on msg from YouTube <iframe>
}
```

I have also tried:

```
window.console = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[youTubeIframe].contentWindow.console;
console['log'] = function(msg){
    // Operate on msg
}
```

What I don't understand is; if I'm able to invoke a console.log message to the YouTube `<iframe>`, then how do I *capture* the console log message? What is the proper way to do this, if there is such a way?

Comment: I suspect that browser security is not allowing you to access the console from another domain.

Comment: @jessehouwing I see what you're saying, but wouldn't it make more sense to block console log messages TO the iframe from another domain?

Comment: Reading them is more essential. Say that a javascript logs a creditcard number to the log, you wouldn't want another domain to read them. If you write to it, what harm can you do :).

Comment: @jessehouwing See if the solution I found helps at all.

Comment: I'll leave the trying to @alok698 or the original poster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On latest version browsers, you can't access any element inside an iFrame from a different domain that the page holding the iframe, i.e. Chrome v31, Firefox v26, IE11.

It worked on some particular browsers' older versions, but this will certainly not work cross-browser.

---

Current browsers that comply with [W3C HTML5 embedded content (including iframes) specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element) not only enforce same-origin policy but also accepts a new `sandbox` attribute to specify even more restrictions to an iframe.

You can see the Browsers that support the new standard in this page:
http://html5test.com/compare/feature/security-sandbox.html

The browsers that accept the new attribute must also comply with the W3C same-origin policy, and hence will not let you access the `console` object (or any other object inside the iframe).